# Density of $H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is defined as the space of all functions in the first Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that are compactly supported. My question is: is $H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Thanks!

Comment: (Yes, it is dense)

Answer (score 2):

A dense subset of a dense subset is dense (easy check using the triangle inequality).

Similarly, if $A \subset B \subset C$ and $A$ is dense in $C$, then $B$ is dense in $C$.

We have $C^1_0 \subset H^1_0$, $C^1$ dense in $H^1$, and $ C^1_0 $ dense in $C^1$. Therefore 
$$ C_0^1 \subset C^1 \subset H^1, $$
so $C_0^1$ is dense in $H^1$ by the first statement, and
$$ C_0^1 \subset H_0^1 \subset H^1, $$
and hence $H_0^1$ is dense in $H^1$ by the second statement.